Tick bid greater than tick ask (negative spread)?
I am parsing tick data using a Perl script and have come across instances where the BID is greater than the ASK for a given tick.
Should I assume this is an error in the tick data (as published) and swap them around, or are there legitimate cases where this may occur, and what would be the circumstances that legitimize this case?
Example:
SYMBOL: AUDUSD
SOURCE: Dukascopy
TICK: 04.01.2010 00:09:01.476 (GMT+0, i.e. no DST)
ASK: 0.89708
BID: 0.8971

If someone can check this tick for this symbol and tell me if they see the same thing, I'd be grateful.
If different, what are your Bid/Ask values?

A negative bid-ask spread is referred to as a Crossed Market and can happen under very high-frequencies in volatile markets. However, it is rare to observe in general and I believe some exchanges try to prevent crossed markets. Eg. For Nasdaq see p. 8 Section VIII "Avoidance of Locked or Crossed Markets" for prevention mechanisms. So, don't immediately assume it to be an error.

Wow, interesting....I'll bear that in mind. Thanks.

You can think of it as an "error condition" or "malfunction" that is rare but can occur, so your program must be able to handle it (perhaps simply by skipping over the time period when it occurs, which should be short).

Thanks @nbbo2. I think I would rather flag and categorize it than ignore it. It could be useful information.

So, I updated my Perl script to 'capture' cases of a Crossed Market (Bid>Ask) and ran it. I made an intriguing observation: on the AUDUSD, these all appear to have ceased after Oct 31st, 2010. I wonder if there was a change to the matching algorithm on the exchange servers that came into effect the next day?
